# How can I calculate $d$ from this equation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

So how can I calculate $d$ from this equation : $17^d \mod 55 = 8 $ ?

I am solving an RSA Encryption question 
and im confused on how the modula is formulated when transferring to the other side, and then how would you calculate d from there
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Google for `discrete logarithm`. It's not $1.13$, it will be an element of $\mathbb Z_{\phi(55)}$.

Answer (score 1):

We need $17^d\equiv8\pmod5\ \ \ \ (1)$ and $17^d\equiv8\pmod{11}\ \ \ \ (2)$

$(1)\implies2^d\equiv8\pmod5\iff2^{d-3}\equiv1\pmod5$

As ord$_52=4,$ we need $d-3\equiv0\pmod4\iff d\equiv3\pmod4\  \ \ \  (3)$

$(2)\implies6^d\equiv8\pmod{11}$

Now $6^2\equiv3\equiv-8\implies6^d\equiv-6^2\iff6^{d-2}\equiv-1\pmod{11}$

Again, $6^3\equiv3\cdot6\equiv7,6^4\equiv3^2\equiv9,6^5=6^2\cdot6^3\equiv3\cdot7\equiv-1$

So, ord$_{11}6=10\implies d-2\equiv5\pmod{10}\iff d\equiv7\pmod{10}\ \ \ \ (4)$

$(4)\implies d\equiv7\pmod2\equiv1$ and $d\equiv7\equiv2\pmod5\ \ \ \ (5)$

$(3)\implies d\equiv3\pmod4\implies d\equiv3\pmod2\equiv1$

As $(5,4)=1$ safely apply [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) on $(3),(5)$

Comment: why mod 5 and not 55

Comment: @lary, As $\pmod{55}\iff\pmod5$  and $\pmod{11}$